# wine-development app.exe can't open file

Tags: wine

Did something changed with the wine environment?

I used a script for ages and few days ago it started giving me troubles

```bsh
wine64-development "$HOME/.wine/drive_c/progs/app/app.exe" \
                  $(winepath-development --windows "$NIXPATH")
```

NIXPATH is a file in my system `/tmp`, with `wineconsole-development` I can create dirs and files into that directory, privilegies of the file looks fine.

`wine-5.6 (Debian 5.6-1)`

Answer (score 1):

Wine being Wine, there's always some regression from one version to another. Do also note that you're using a sid version of Wine, which will brings even more bugs.

Comment: Sid is more stable than they say, I've been using it for decades, only Chromium lately has given me some problems every now and then, always solved in a few days. For wine I switched to the non "-development" version and it seems to work (and I filed a bug).

Comment: Just because it works for you, doesn't mean it'll be the same for everyone else. Even Debian Stable has bugs.